# Material tiling and offset in unity

Tags: unity, textures, shaders

***Ambiguity:***
What exactly is the difference between Tiling the material and Offset of material?

***Need to do:***

I need the material to be repeated `n` times on the object where I need to set the value of `n` via script.How do I do it?

It seems to happen through Tiling(tried via inspector) but again what is difference between `mainTextureOffset` and `setTextureOffset`?

*Tried:*

Following is the line of code that I tried to repeat the texture `n` number of times on an object(repeat across the width of object), but it does nothing significant that I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What exactly is the difference between Tiling the material and Offset
>   of material?

Those parameters set by the inspector are used inside the shader to scale the texture coordinates.
A `uniform float4` in the shader with the name of the texture and `_ST suffix` is populated with those values.
For example considered the main texture:

```
float2 scaled_uv = tex.uv * _MainTex_ST.xy + _MainTex_ST.zw;
```

Let's say the offset basically translate the texture in the uv space meanwhile the scale, scales it.

**mainTextureOffset**: set the texture offset of the main texture (texture binded to the name `_MainTex` inside a shader)

[SetTextureOffset](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetTextureOffset.html) let you specify the texture name. `SetTexureOffset(_MainTex, offset);`is equivalent to use the facility `mainTextureOffset`.

An alternative is setting directly the uniform vector. The used convention for built-in shaders is using the suffix _ST to the texture name. So you can also use [SetVector](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetVector.html):

```
material.SetVector("_MainTex_ST", scaleAndOffset);
```

---

EDIT

For repeat the texture you have to modify the scale not the offset. If you set for example a scale of 2 along an uv axis you will obtain to repeat the texture twice along it.

Comment: Thanks you,So, I guess offset should do the repeating of texture n times?

Answer (score 1):

Documentation on the website which also happens to be the first search result for the term `SetTextureOffset` or `mainTextureOffset` seems to sum up the issue nicely.

## [`Material.SetTextureOffset`](http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/Material.SetTextureOffset.html)

> ```
> function SetTextureOffset (propertyName : String, offset : Vector2) : void
> ```
>
> ## Description
>
> Sets the placement offset of texture `propertyName`.
>
> Common texture names used by Unity's builtin shaders:
>
> - `"_MainTex"` is the main diffuse texture. 
>     This can also be accessed via ***`mainTextureOffset`*** property.
> - `"_BumpMap"` is the normal map.
> - `"_Cube"` is the reflection cubemap.

## [`Material.mainTextureOffset`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-mainTextureOffset.html)

> ```
> var mainTextureOffset: Vector2;
> ```
>
> ## Description
>
> The texture offset of the main texture.
>
> The same as using `GetTextureOffset` or `SetTextureOffset` with `"_MainTex"` name

A material has a main texture, which is the one you see. Additionally, it can have other textures, such as a bump or cube map which affect how the object's appearance is calculated. `mainTextureOffset` only affects the material's main texture. `SetTextureOffset` lets you specify the name of the texture to offset, so `SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", .05)` would be eqivalent to `mainTextureOffset = .05;`